# How to use auto canditate false or exclude bean inside pojo Spring rather than xml?

Tags: java, spring

I have Beans class

```
class A{
 @Autowired
  B b;

  ......
}
Class Config{
 @Bean
 A a(){
  return new A();
 }
}
Class Test{
 @Autowired
 A a;
 void doSom(){
   a.blabla();
 }
  public static void main(String[] args){
   ..........
   }
}
```

My question here,When i inject A in Test class, b also should have the object. else we will get no bean type exception B....So other than required false in autowired, is there any other way to exclude while spring initialize this A class and b should get create based on some conditions .Can you please help or guide how to exclude beans while running Test class

Comment: What are you wanting to accomplish?

Comment: i dont want inject dependency injection . i want to exclude while A created